# How can I call a function in another process

Tags: linux, event-handling, ipc, rpc, publish-subscribe

How can I call a "function of  process" in another process?
I want to implement publish/subscribe pattern via this method between multiple process in Linux with C or C++ languages.

Comment: You can't call a function in another process directly. You need to devise an inter-process communication protocol, and implement it in both processes. You can use message queues or sockets to send the data.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks for response, it is not important if I cannot call a function in another process directly, I want to call a function in another process with any way( such as RPC or one technique with IPC) to implement publish/subscribe pattern. I want to know this way.

Comment: Use a message queue or Unix-domain socket to communicate between the processes. Your question is so general that it's hard to provide a decent answer. You can't really believe that this broad topic can be explained in a couple of paragraphs, can you?

Comment: @Barmar: ok, I can assume that I have one way to IPC but the main problem still remain. how can I call a function in another process with IPC? or in the other word how to fire event in another process?

Comment: You don't. The other process has to be waiting for something to arrive via IPC. When it reads that data, it performs some action in response.

Comment: @Barmar: ok, with this assumption how can I register a call back that when some data arrives from another process OS call it.

Comment: If you use an RPC library, it will be part of that library. If not, you don't register anything, you just sit in a loop reading data from the IPC channel, and process it in whatever way you want.

Comment: @Barmar: did you know any RPC library that have something like this in linux?

Answer (score 1):

You may use **gdb** to attach to the process and execute some function, example:

```
$ gdb -p 17304
Attaching to process 17304
[...]
(gdb) call getppid()
$1 = 29136
```

In gdb run `(gdb) info functions` to see them.

Comment: I need a programming model for this usage.

Comment: `call getppid()` may fail with "*'getppid' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type*" . In that case, add the [called-function-appropriate *return type* cast](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html#SYNOPSIS): `call (pid_t) getppid()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was already explained you need to read up on IPC - there are plenty options. However, from your “publishing” intention I think you could do with a simple file. Update it with that function() return value in one process in a loop. So all other processes on your system could read it.